# Can a parameter pack in function template be followed by another parameter which depends on the return type?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, variadic-templates

I have a function where a template type parameter follows a parameter pack. It looks like this:

```cpp
template<typename...Args, typename T>
T* default_factory_func()
{
    return new T;
}
```

Visual C++ compiler rejects it with an error `C3547: template parameter 'T' cannot be used because it follows a template parameter pack and cannot be deduced from the function parameters of 'default_factory_func'`.

However, I tried various versions of GCC (starting with 4.4.7) and clang (starting with 3.1) available on Compiler Explorer, and all of them compile such code just fine.

```cpp
// this code is just a minimal example condensed
// from a much more complex codebase
template<typename T>
T* construct(T* (*factory_func)())
{
    return factory_func();
}

template<typename...Args, typename T>
T* default_factory_func() // C3547 on this line
{
    return new T(Args()...);
}

struct some_class {
    some_class(int, int, int) {}
};

int main()
{
    construct<some_class>(
        default_factory_func<int,int,int>
    );
}
```

Is this some quirk of MSVC or is it not allowed by the standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the standard is confused here (probably needs an issue if one doesn't already exist).

- The definition of `default_factory_func` is ill-formed per [[temp.param]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#14.sentence-3)

> A template parameter pack of a function template shall not be followed by another template parameter unless that template parameter can be deduced from the parameter-type-list ([dcl.fct]) of the function template or has a default argument

- At the same time, the types of `default_factory_func` can be (arguably) deduced per [[temp.deduct.funcaddr]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.funcaddr) because you are attempting to match a target type of `some_class*(*)(void)` when you pass `&default_factory_func<int,int,int>`

> Template arguments can be deduced from the type specified when taking the address of an overload set. If there is a target, the function template's function type and the target type are used as the types of P and A, and the deduction is done as described in [temp.deduct.type]. Otherwise, deduction is performed with empty sets of types P and A

<sup>(Thanks to [n.m.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m) for pointing this second one out in their [now-deleted-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69094460/27678))</sup>

I think the safest bet would be to avoid running afoul of the first rule by reordering your template arguments:

```
template<class T, typename...Args>
T* default_factory_func()
{
    return new T(Args()...);
}
```

And then explicitly casting your function pointer to resolve the overload:

```
auto foo = construct(
    static_cast<some_class*(*)()>(default_factory_func<some_class, int, int, int>)
);
```

#### [Live Code](https://godbolt.org/z/5rWaMa6cs)

(Compiles on gcc/clang/and msvc latest)